# Error with F1 score: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'item'

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I try to train NN for binary labels, here is my data:

```
 Train: {'0': 126315, '1': 2915}
    Val  : {'0': 31579, '1': 729}
    Test : {'0': 27864, '1': 643}
```

Here is my weights:

```
tensor([7.9167e-06, 3.4305e-04], device='cuda:0')
```

I get this warnings:

```
C:\Users\___\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\sampler.py:115: UserWarning: To copy construct from a tensor, it is recommended to use sourceTensor.clone().detach() or sourceTensor.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True), rather than torch.tensor(sourceTensor).
  self.weights = torch.tensor(weights, dtype=torch.double)
NN_FullyConnected(
  (layer_1): Linear(in_features=611, out_features=512, bias=True)
  (layer_2): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=256, bias=True)
  (layer_3): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=128, bias=True)
  (layer_4): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=64, bias=True)
  (layer_5): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=32, bias=True)
  (layer_out): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=2, bias=True)
  (relu): ReLU()
  (dropout): Dropout(p=0.45)
  (batchnorm1): BatchNorm1d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (batchnorm2): BatchNorm1d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (batchnorm3): BatchNorm1d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (batchnorm4): BatchNorm1d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (batchnorm5): BatchNorm1d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
)

Begin training.
C:\Users\__\PycharmProjects\myproject\network_creator_nn.py:50: UserWarning: Implicit dimension choice for log_softmax has been deprecated. Change the call to include dim=X as an argument.
  y = nn.LogSoftmax()(x)
C:\Users\__\PycharmProjects\__\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1145: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no true samples.
  'recall', 'true', average, warn_for)

Epoch 000: | Train Loss: 0.66666 | Val Loss: 0.68134 | Train Acc: 0.835| Val Acc: 0.498 | Train F_score: 4.892| Val F_score: 7.191
2020-07-14 08:47:07
Epoch 001: | Train Loss: 0.48715 | Val Loss: 0.73657 | Train Acc: 0.850| Val Acc: 0.040 | Train F_score: 18.034| Val F_score: 4.398


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/__/PycharmProjects/__/complete_proccess.py", line 239, in <module>
    val_epoch_f_score += val_f_score.item()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'item'
```

Why I got this error after 2 epochs? my F1 score function is:

```
def binary_f1_score(y_pred, y_test):
    y_pred_tag = torch.log_softmax(y_pred, dim=1)
    _, y_pred_tags = torch.max(y_pred_tag, dim=1)
    f_result = f1_score(y_test.cpu().numpy(), y_pred_tags.cpu().numpy())
    f_result = f_result * 100
    return f_result
```

If I add to the f1 score function the argument "macro" it will works well, but I don't know why
Thank you

Comment: `val_f_score` is not tensor in your case but a `float` object of python, you can remove `.item()` method from that line